# html e css, seletor de links através de ancoras, com setas next e prev

Tags: html5, css3

Alguém poderia me dar uma dica de como fazer um seletor de links através de ancoras, com setas de avançar e recuar, parecido com o da imagem aí?? pois só sei utilizar ancoras através de slides ou com target display:block e none. queria um do mesmo jeito do da imagem ou parecido só que com setas na laterias, uma de recuar e outra de avançar, já procurei no google e não consegui achar um tutorial a respeito disso    https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO1py.png

Comment: Qual imagem?....

Comment: eu acabei de editar a pergunta, a imagem eu já inseri aí no final do texto

Comment: Cara sua pergunta está muito confusa, seu problema deve ser fácil de resolver, mas o pessoal tem que entender o que vc precisa realmente.

Comment: Vc quer só o CSS com o estilo similar ao da imagem, uma seta de cada lado e a paginação no meio?

Comment: Sim eu quero com setas nas laterais e a numeração no meio, mas é incrível que eu consigo fazer com slides e não com links, que aparentam ser bem mais simples kkkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O bootstrap tem alguns exemplos prontos, como segue abaixo

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Se você usar o [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination) será mais fácil ainda bastando apenas usar o seguinte comando

```
{{ $users->links() }}
```

Fonte: [Pagination](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/pagination/)

Comment: Nossa! era o que eu queria, muito obrigado!

Comment: Eu consegui achar no w3schools e não consegui fazer as setas passarem de forma linear por cima de cada link numerado, cara eu não estou entendendo de como setar cada link de forma ordenada um após o outro, pois utilizado um unica seta para seleciona-los tá bem complicado, é só por causa das setas se deixar só os números é possível e também eles não ficaram marcados na página que o usuário estiver

Comment: Por que voce nao usa um framework, como o Laravel?

Comment: Eu consegui, separei a  estilização do seletor em varias paginas html, e definindo links diferentes conforme o usuário pressionar na seta e avançar para próxima página é meio complicado, mas o negocio é utilizar o iframe pegando apenas o seletor e adicionando as paginas de forma ordenada apenas mudando a ordem do links no seletor numérico